# Additional relation between records in Rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend

I need your small advice help.

I have trivial models: `Post` and `User`. 
A user `has_many :posts` and a post `belongs_to :user`. A post has one owner.

I need somehow add an additional relation: a post can have multiple contributors. A contributor is a user too. I need to be able to write something like this: `@post.contributors` (shows User records) and `@user.contributed_to` (shows Post records).

How do I do that?

Comment: I've generated a migration with foreign keys and generated a new Contributor model with `belongs_to :post` and `has_one :user`

But how do I assign a user to post as a post? `Contributor.create(User.first, Post.first)` is not working. neither do `Post.first.contributors.create(User.first)` =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need many-to-many association here, because `user` has_many `posts` and `posts` has_many `users`.

To implement it, you need to create an additional model (for example, `contribution` with `user_id` and `post_id` columns)

```
class Contribution < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And your `Post` and `User` classes will contain something like this:

```
class Post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :contributions
  has_many :contributors, through: :contributions, source: :user
end

class User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :contributions
  has_many :contributed_posts, through: :contributions, source: :post
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Ihar! But how do I add a contribution?

Comment: As a usual Rails model: `rails g model contribution user:belongs_to post:belongs_to`

Comment: And an instance of a Contribution is added like this: `Contribution.create(user: @user, post: @post)` where `@user` is a contributor and `@post` is the post to contribute

Comment: Thanks a lot Ihar!